# upload files azure blob storage using container url

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I am able to upload files to azure blob storage using below C# code,

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("StorageKey");

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = 
blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\myfile"))
{
  blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Here I'm supplying blob storage connection string and container name.

Now, I can see I have URL under `Container Properties`,

```
https://test.blob.core.windows.net/containerId
```

Question, can I write C# code that will user above `URL` to upload files instead of using connection string/container name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, and the reason is simple: `/` is a valid char for container name. EG: you can have the container named `mycontainer/folder/subFolder`